# How to get python to constantly check for key combinations even if it is in the background?

Tags: python

I was thinking of coding a script that will run in the background of my computer that will detect key combinations to start specific tasks.

For example, the user presses Ctrl+Alt+F1 then the browser starts. However, I cannot seem to find a way to detect these combinations while the script is running in the background.

I thought of using a .pyw extension for my script, but that makes the script not interact-able.

If anyone needs to know, my OS is Windows 10.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, verifiable example ( http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your current attempt at getting it to work. Also, provide what operating system you are using (as that definitely matters with key bindings), and what version of Python.

Comment: Well I have not yet attempted the project.... I am still planning and found that this is a problem. Thus, I cannot provide an example.

Answer (score 1):

I think the [`pyHook`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyHook) library is what you're looking for:

> The pyHook package provides callbacks for global mouse and keyboard events in Windows. Python applications register event handlers for user input events such as left mouse down, left mouse up, key down, etc. and set the keyboard and/or mouse hook.